# Android: App exits when trying to save image to SD card

Tags: android, image, save, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I am trying to save image to SD card and I added some code for it.But after clicking the "OK"/Checkmark in the camera, my app exits.Would I have to check if the directory that I am trying to store it in exists?How would i do that?..   !file.exists(){file.mkdirs}?   ..In my code I have tried to store it in /Android folder which exists in every SD card.

```
           file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                 + "/Android/" + "bhe_app" + ".jpg");

    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        startActivityForResult(i, cameraData);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the directory before creating the File.

```
boolean createdDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/directory1/directory2/directory3/").mkdirs();
```

the variable `createdDirectory` will be

> true if and only if the directory was created, along with all
>   necessary parent directories; false otherwise

You will have to make sure that your app has the permission to write to the SD Card(Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the permission to `Write_External_Storage` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, thats important for saving the pics on the sd card

Comment: i just did..but the app still exits after I hit the"OK"/check mark button of the camera..would this be because there is no directory as such?...and how to check if the directory exits and it not create it..something to do with dir.mkdirs() ?

Comment: whats the error, see it in the Log, and try to store the image directly on the sd card instead of putting it in the directory

Comment: I was looking through the google's tutorials and I made a few changes to the code.Now, the image is saved, but once I hit the checkmark for the camera,the app exits.I made a few changes like:
 file = new File(
Environment .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "BHE App");mediaFile = newFile(file.getPath()+File.separator
            +"Image1.jpg"); if (!file.exists()) { try {file.createNewFile();
           } catch (IOException e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            } } imageUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);

Comment: And i use the imageUri to say:
i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
   i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imageUri);